# apostophe inside EXEC

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to run this script

```
EXEC('      
BEGIN TRAN
if exists ( select name from sys.indexes where name='IX_IdDimX')
    begin
    DROP INDEX [IX_IdDimX] ON [dbo].[FacX]
    END
COMMIT ')
```

in SQL but then the apostophes inside make it wrong. even adding \ before ' like in java to make it interpret it as char and not special value but it doesn't solve it

Answer (score 2):

put another apostrophe around IX_IdDimx

```
EXEC('      
BEGIN TRAN
if exists ( select name from sys.indexes where name=''IX_IdDimX'')
    begin
    DROP INDEX [IX_IdDimX] ON [dbo].[FacX]
    END
COMMIT ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either double the single quotes in the string or use a parameterized query like the example below.

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN TRAN;
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT name FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = @IndexName)
    BEGIN
        DROP INDEX [IX_IdDimX] ON [dbo].[FacX];
    END;
    COMMIT;'
, N'@IndexName sysname'
, @IndexName = 'IX_IdDimX';
```